# PHP Печать

Tags: php, печать

Вопрос: можно ли работать с принтером через php? если да, то какие функции используются для печати?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С принтером можно работать из PHP. Для этого предназначены [функции семейства printer_XXX](http://my.php.net/manual/en/ref.printer.php).